# How to change DetailPage Data when Masterpage ListView Item is selected Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have created a master-Detail Page in Xamarin Forms. I have created only one DetailPage for each items of MasterPage. So, when i click MasterPage Items only data should change not the Layout/Contents of the DetailPage. Please help me.

MasterPage:

```
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProductSelctionScreen : MasterDetailPage
{
    public string customer;

    public ProductSelctionScreen(string Customer)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        customer = Customer;

        DetailPage.Choosedcustomer.Text = customer;

        MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
    }

    public void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as ProductSelctionScreenMenuItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
        page.Title = item.Title;



        switch (page.Title)
        {
            case "Foods":

                if (DetailPage.productListView.ItemsSource != null)
                {
                    DetailPage.productListView.ItemsSource = null;

                    BindingContext = new ProductItemModel1();

                    DetailPage.productListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("ProductList"));

                    DetailPage.productListView.SelectedItem = null;
                }


                break;

            case "Beverages":
                break;

            case "Personal Care":
                break;

            case "Health Supplements":
                break;

            case "Cosmetics":
                break;

            case "Ayurveda Medicines":
                break;
        }

        Detail = new NavigationPage(page);

        IsPresented = false;

        MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }

}
```

On Clicking an item in masterPage I want to change the ItemSource of DetailPage Listview(below)

DetailPage Xamlfile :

```
        <ListView x:Name="ProductListView" ItemsSource="{Binding BeverageList}" HasUnevenRows="True"  SeparatorVisibility="None"     >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>


                    <local:Productdata/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following -
1.the code of your MasterPage
2.the code of your DetailPage and 
3.the action that your code is taking on selection of a ListView item.

Comment: It's better to create new Content Page for all Items. Otherwise you have to add all content in Single Detail Page and display it conditionally.